# Declaration of function to generate vector of class with a vector of another class

Tags: c++, function, vector, class-design

I have 2 classes:

```
class Item;
class Component;
```

And I have a function to generate a `vector` of `Item`s from a `vector` of `Component`s

```
static vector<Item> generateItemsFromComponents( vector<Component> components )
{
    vector<Item> vi;
    // ...
    return vi;
}
```

My question is, where do I declare this function? In the `Item` class or in the `Component` class? Or the class design is wrong? Maybe suggest better methods to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like a job for `std::transform` or a short ranged-for.

Comment: Free function in the same namespace as `Item` and `Component`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if there is a 1 to 1 conversion function from a `Component` to an `Item`, you should consider :

- Having an explicit conversion method in `Component`, e.g. `Item ToItem();`, or
- Having an implicit conversion operator, but this is **unlikely** unless automatic conversion (by the compiler) would make sense in any case.

e.g :

```
 operator const Item&() const;
```

Once you have the single conversion function available, the method that operates on containers does not really belong to any of your existing interfaces (unless you have a class for containers of Components already), so it makes sense to declare a free function :

**Example:**

```
vector<Item> generateItemsFromComponents( const vector<Component>& components )
{
    vector<Item> vi;
    for(auto& comp in components)
       vi.push_back(comp.ToItem());
    return vi;
}
```

However, as pointed by @chris, using `std::transform` directly, together with a lambda, makes things easier:

**Example:**

```
vector<Item> vi;
transform(begin(comp), end(comp), back_inserter(vi), [](Component c){ return c.ToItem(); }
```

The advantages of this last method:

1. You are not dependent on the container type : you operate on iterators, `comp` could be any standard compliant container, not just a `vector`.
2. It might be more efficient, and is definitely very readable

---

**Answer:**

- Provide a single conversion function in the Component class
- Use the standard `<algorithm>` together with this function
- Consider lambdas as a substitute for very simple functions
- If a function is not related to a type, just make it a free function